# Cluster autoscaler v1.0.4 kubernetes error

Tags: kubernetes

im getting below error

```
W0316 22:04:26.025272       1 clusterstate.go:514] Failed to get nodegroup for <nodename>: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got 
W0316 22:04:26.025296       1 clusterstate.go:514] Failed to get nodegroup for <nodename>: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got 
W0316 22:04:26.025303       1 clusterstate.go:514] Failed to get nodegroup for <nodename>: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got 
W0316 22:04:26.025309       1 clusterstate.go:514] Failed to get nodegroup for <nodename>: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got 
W0316 22:04:26.025316       1 clusterstate.go:514] Failed to get nodegroup for <nodename>: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got 
W0316 22:04:26.025324       1 clusterstate.go:514] Failed to get nodegroup for <nodename>: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got 
W0316 22:04:26.025340       1 clusterstate.go:560] Readiness for node group *** not found

    E0316 22:04:02.705833       1 static_autoscaler.go:257] Failed to scale up: failed to build node infos for node groups: Wrong id: expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got
```

using cluster-autoscasler

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler
```

Comment: Do you have `--cloud-config=` in your apiserver's arguments? Do you have the Nodes tagged with either [`KubernetesCluster` or `kubernetes.io/cluster/$cid`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.9.3/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/aws/tags.go#L34-L39)?

Comment: @Matthew L Daniel sorry I’m newbie in Kubernetes I followed this git https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples/cluster-autoscaler-one-asg.yaml   Where should I add —cloud-config ?? Also why should I tag Nodes because I’m planning to add different tag to few nodes to separate my pods deployment

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel can you please clarify --cloud-config what should be this value for aws?

Answer (score 3):

That happened because some of your nodes do not have a tag which identifies your node group.

As @Matthew L Daniel mentioned in his comment, it needs a tag on AWS instance for working properly.

Here is from [official documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#internals) about how identification works and why:

> It is assumed that the underlying cluster is run on top of some kind of node groups. Inside a node group, all machines have identical capacity and have the same set of assigned labels. Thus, increasing a size of a node group will create a new machine that will be similar to those already in the cluster - they will just not have any user-created pods running (but will have all pods run from the node manifest and daemon sets.)

As you can find in [installation documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws#auto-discovery-setup):

> To run a cluster-autoscaler which auto-discovers ASGs with nodes use the --node-group-auto-discovery flag and tag the ASGs with key k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled and key kubernetes.io/cluster/< YOUR CLUSTER NAME >.

So, just add that tags to your nodes.

Also, you can use as many AWS tags and Kubernetes labels for a node as you want, it will not affect autoscaler.

**UPD:**

The reason why Autoscaler was not working and crashed on getting `ProviderID` was in a missed `--cloud-provider` option value in [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubelet/). Addin `aws` value should fix that kind of issues.

Comment: Ok but why does it says “expected format aws:///<zone>/<name>, got ” ? What does that mean ?

Comment: It just an internal format of ID name in Autoscaler. Here is an [implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/88d97c2254a4fa35071815af878945af9131a87a/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/aws_cloud_provider.go#L126). So, don't think about it, just add a tag.

Comment: Do I also need to add --node-group-auto-discovery:true in cluster-autoscaler deployment yaml ?

Comment: If you want to automatically add new Autoscaling Groups and lets Autoscaler manage them - yes, you need that option, otherwise, you can just add a static list of ASG which you want to manage by Autoscailer - you can check an [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/21e9da59362ff4dea77930ecbe505057a1306827/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples/cluster-autoscaler-one-asg.yaml#L139) how to define that groups without discovery.

Comment: Sorry...This is exactly how I’m specifying Aws ASG name in CA deployment yaml ,but where in here I need to specify Tags , I do know I can add a Tag on Aws ASG instances but how do I map it to CA and is there any specific format for Tags?

Comment: If I understood you right, you want to know how to add that tags to a configuration of your CA. From an official [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/21e9da59362ff4dea77930ecbe505057a1306827/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples/cluster-autoscaler-autodiscover.yaml#L140), you only need to change a cluster name in that line: `--node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,kubernetes.io/cluster/<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>`. So, the tag name is `k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled`, value - `kubernetes.io/cluster/<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>`.

Comment: As per your earlier comment you mentioned this is required if I need auto discovery otherwise im just adding Asg name , this is where I’m confused when you say  “otherwise, you can just add a static list of ASG which you want to manage by Autoscailer”. Which I’m already doing without using auto discovery

Comment: Lemme know if I have to use auto discovery to get rid of this error ?

Comment: And where is the asg name in this?  --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,kubernetes.io/cluster/<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167056/discussion-between-anton-kostenko-and-shiv455).